# Why can't I use multiple LIKE NOT in google query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am currently trying to narrow down my data. I want to eliminate certain values that I do not want to pull in the query.

First I want to eliminate the - (dash)

```
=query(A1:B,"select A where NOT A LIKE '%-%'") 
That works,
```

But, if I want to continue to narrow down my data I use

```
=query(A1:B,"select A where NOT A LIKE '%-%' or NOT A LIKE '%WOLF%'")
```

That does not work. Instead of narrowing down my data it adds the dash back and keeps wolf . How can I keep using NOT like for multiple strings?
[image]

Comment: I think you meant to use AND instead of OR ?

Comment: tried that, does not work.

Comment: Please explain "that does not work"

Comment: Look at the last column please. The last query I used does not remove the Dash or remove the wolf..

Answer (score 3):

Use parentheses to make the logic easier to follow, like this:

`=query(A1:A, "where not (A like '%-%' or A like '%WOLF%')", 0)`

Comment: such a small inprovement. lol but that is perfect

Comment: Does that work with using LIKE or with multiple variables?

Comment: See [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 0):

better to use regex like:

```
=QUERY(A1:A, "where not A matches '.*-.*|.*WOLF.*'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this conversation, the second query will return anything that does not have Wolf AND a dash in it. So if I have "Wolf-man" and "Gray Wolf" in my data. I will get "Gray Wolf" back but not "Wolf-Man." Why?
The OR operator tells the query to return something if it's not like one OR the other. "Gray Wolf" is not like '%-%'. Even though it would get filtered by the OR '%Wolf%' language, it's captured by the first part of the OR statement, and so the query says "Yes, this is like this or that, since it is like your no-dash language, I'll return it." And visa versa. If you had "Mole-person" in your data, that would pop up, since it's not like '%Wolf%' and the query will say "well, i's got a dash but it's not a wolf, so I'll include it."

Users above suggested the AND operator, since that is what you'll need in order to filter out BOTH wolves AND dashes. The way it is written, a cell must be like BOTH for the query to exclude it.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Hey, this is more of a coment than an answer